# Installing GraphicsMagick on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, node.js, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, graphicsmagick

I am trying to install GraphicsMagick on Mountain Lion and having problems. I tried all the things that I could search for in blogs and other stackoverflow questions but nothing worked. So I have put the full stack of errors I get on each command. Please look and help me out.

When I run

```
brew install graphicsmagick
```

I get this

```
Warning: Could not link jpeg. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link jpeg'
```

and

```
Warning: Could not link libpng. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link libpng'
```

and in the last I am getting

```
==> make install
Warning: Could not link graphicsmagick. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link graphicsmagick'

Possible conflicting files are:
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.18: 283 files, 10M, built in 52 seconds
```

Now if I try to `brew link jpeg` or `brew link libpng` I get this error

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d... Warning: Could not link jpeg. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/wrjpgcom
Target /usr/local/bin/wrjpgcom already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

If I try the overwrite method by doing `brew link --overwrite jpeg` it worked. But '`brew link --overwrite libpng`' I get this

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14... Warning: Could not link libpng. Unlinking...

Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/share/man/man5/png.5
```

And after that when I try `brew link graphicsmagick` I get:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.18... Warning: Could not link graphicsmagick. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.18/share/man/man5/quantize.5
/usr/local/share/man/man5 is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `brew doctor` tell you?

Answer (score 41):

Try removing everything and start again:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick graphicsmagick libpng jpeg
brew cleanup -s
brew install graphicsmagick
```

Solved me some issues recently

Comment: If you still get permission errors, run 'sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local'

Comment: Thanks for the syntax on installing graphics magick on Mac. Does this installation include the extension for PHP? Trying to access in an app, getting Class 'GMagick' not found.