# How to generate a random image of specified file size (e.g. x Kb) using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image

I am working on some project where I need to have a lot of image files (preferably in jpg) format of predefined sizes (Not the height and width but file size in Kb/Mb).

So I might need to generate a random image of 100 KB in size and another random image of 2 MB in size.

How should I go about this using NodeJS?

I found [this Random Image Generator code](https://github.com/davidpadbury/random-image-generator/blob/master/bin/random-image-generator.js) to generate a random image but it does not allow me to specify the file size.

All suggestions and wild guesses are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

I don't speak node, but at the command line using ImageMagick, this will get you a large JPEG image:

```
convert -size 1000x2000 xc:gray +noise gaussian large.jpg
```

If you then use `-define jpeg:extent=400kb` on that you will get a 400kb file, +/- a little:

```
convert large.jpg -define jpeg:extent=400kb 400kb.jpg
```

Change the `400kb` to suit your needs. If you want to do it all in one go, you can do this:

```
convert -size 1000x2000 xc:gray +noise gaussian jpg: | convert -define jpeg:extent=400kb - 400kb.jpg
```

In node, can you use the raw interface? It'll look something like

```
im.convert(['-size','1000x2000','xc:gray','+noise','gaussian','output.jpg'],
   function(...)
```

Comment: I'll chime in, here is an answer I gave about using imagemagick from node https://stackoverflow.com/a/16106655/1380669

Answer (score 1):

You need to work out what dimensions and DPI will give you the file-size you want. Given that you don't seem to care too much about what the image looks like, let's pick 100 DPI pseudo-randomly.

An image that is `x` inches by `y` inches at 100 DPI will take up

```
(100*x)*(100*y)==fileSize
```

per colour channel. If you're looking for full colour, you'll need three of these, so

```
3*(100*x)*(100*y)==fileSize
```

Now you need to drop in your `fileSize`, pick a value for `x` or `y`, solve for the other value and generate an image of size `x` by `y` at 100 DPI to produce your required filesize.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Let me try this out.